# Check for dash before applying titleize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really new to Ruby and Rails and need to know how to check if a string contains a dash before applying titlelize.

```
@city = City.first :conditions => { :title => params[:city].titleize }
```

What I need to do is:

```
@city = City.first :conditions => { :title => params[:city] }
```

and then write something that will apply titleize ONLY if the `@city` variable doesn't contain a dash.

Comment: Would it not just be `@city.titleize if @city.include? '-'`

Comment: That's what I was thinking but now I'm getting this: syntax error, unexpected '\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this solution added by zachrose a couple of weeks ago: https://gist.github.com/varyonic/ccda540c417a6bd49aec

```
def nice_title(phrase)
  return phrase if phrase =~ /^-+$/
  phrase.split('-').map { |part|
    if part.chars.count == part.bytes.count
      part.titleize
    else
      part.split(' ').map { |word| word.mb_chars.titleize }.join(' ')
    end
  }.join('-')
end
```

Comment: The link is dead. Can you pls write it here?

Answer (score 0):

```
if params[:city] =~ /-/
  @city = City.first :conditions => { :title => params[:city] }
else
  @city = City.first :conditions => { :title => params[:city].titleize }     
end
```

I do not know why you are using this, but I believe it will not work for all cases.  There should be a better approach.

Comment: I'm trying to fix an issue with an existing project. The database contains a list of cities. Some contain dashes and some do not. For some reason, the cities that contain dashes are breaking when titleize is being applied to them. If I remove it, cities with spaces are breaking. The most simple solution I could come up with is to check for the dash before applying titleize.

Comment: But isn't params[:city] coming from the user?  it can be anything, why title it?  What do you mean they are breaking?  You just want to query on it.

Comment: I wish I could explain it better but I don't really understand what's going on myself. I have a bunch of cities and some of them have spaces in the name and some have special characters. For some reason, all the cities work with titleize applied to the params[:city] except for the cities with dashes in them. I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to have rails except those cities with dashes from having titleize applied to them.